# My selection tool in ArcMap doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, select

I have been trying to choose some features (rivers) by the selection tool in ArcMap but it seems that it doesn't work. I only have one layer and want to select some features on it. I don't understand why the selection tool can not select the rivers I am putting in its square. I drag the tool over the features and unfortunately, it doesn't highlight them. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Is the layer set as selectable?

Comment: Yes, I did put it as selectable many times but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you able to select part of the feature if you open the attribute table for the rivers and select it that way?

Comment: Have you changed and subsequently forgotten the selection type? Maybe you changed it to remove from current selection for example?

Comment: Yes, to expand on the answer from Hornbydd.  Go to the Selection drop-down menu.  Expand 'Interactive Selection Method', Ensure that 'Create New Selection' is the selected choice and not something like 'Remove from Current Selection'.  Make sure you are using the 'Select Features' button and not the 'Select Element' button to select the features.

Comment: Thank you so much GBG, my problem was that the option " Removed from current selection" was checked. I removed the check. Thank you.